# How to create List of common element from two different List in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Two List.

```
List<String> A=['1','2','3','4','5'];
List<String> B=['4','5','6','7'];
```

How to create common element list ?

**output**

```
List<String> C=['4','5'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `.toSet()`

```
List<String> a=['1','2','3','4','5'];
List<String> b=['4','5','6','7'];

List<int> c = a.toSet().where((element) => b.toSet().contains(element)).toList();
```

Comment: What if the lists can contain duplicates? a Set requires unique values so this wouldn't work in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> A=['1','2','3','4','5'];
List<String> B=['4','5','6','7'];

  A.removeWhere((item) => !B.contains(item));

  print(A);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert List to Set using Set.from
then use Set's Set.intersection function
like

```
final characters1 = <String>{'A', 'B', 'C'}; //Set1
final characters2 = <String>{'A', 'E', 'F'}; //Set2 
final unionSet = characters1.intersection(characters2);
print(unionSet); // {A}
```

then use Set.toList() method on result Set

Answer (score 0):

which list have more length apply loop for that list and check conditon for another list
[image: This is the solution]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet